# Filters in Spring boot framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, filter

I am new to exploring web filters in spring framework. Can anyone explain why does implementing `org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean` work while `javax.servlet.Filter` throws `java.lang.AbstractMethodError` when deploying and starting application in apache tomcat.

Tomcat version is 8.5.59 and my application is using 2.1.0.RELEASE for spring boot.

Comment: You **extend** `GenericFilterBean` and you **implement** `Filter`. One is a class the other an interface, without implementing the methods you will get an error (like you did).

Comment: I tried implementing init() and destroy() as well in my custom filter class (implemented by Filter interface), but tomcat server was still throwing this exception upon startup.

Comment: There are more methods you need to implement, which is what the error is telling you. You are also probably using a lower version of the servlet API in your development as for running which will lead to these kinds of errors to.

Comment: @M.Deinum, got your point. I guess the version of the servlet API is differing. Thanks